# The lodash way to delete nested array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array like:

`[[0,1,2,3][0,1,2,3,][0,1,2,3][0,1,2,3]]`

I want to slice the nested arrays to keep only the first two elements.

I am using this code with lodash:

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        data[i] = _.slice(data[i], [start=0], [end=2]);
  }
```

This doesn't feel very lodash though. How would you approach it?

Comment: If you associate functional programming with loadash (and if that's what you mean by "feel very loadash"), maybe you are looking for `_.map`. Otherwise I don't know what "feel very lodash" is supposed to mean.

Comment: do you want to get a new array, or mutate an existing one?

Comment: @dandavis _.map looks pretty good. I can mutate or create, whichever's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
var data = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]];
_.invoke(data, 'slice', 0, 2);
```

Otherwise, if you want to use map:

```
data.map(function(item) { return item.slice(0, 2); }); // pure js solution
_.map(data, function(item) { return _.slice(item, 0, 2); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
var collection = [
    [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
];

_.map(collection, _.ary(_.partialRight(_.take, 2), 1));
// → [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ] ]
```

Here's what's going on:

- The [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) function is making sure the callback only gets one argument passed to it, the collection item.
- The [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) function is partially-applying `2` to the `take()` function as the second argument. The first argument will be the collection item.
- The [take()](https://lodash.com/docs#take) function is taking the first `n` items from the array.